# Overridden error message not being displayed in serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a ListField serializer where if it's empty, it should display the appropriate message:

```
class CreatePostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        read_only=True,
    )

    topics = serializers.ListField(
        child=serializers.CharField(
            max_length=50,
            error_messages={'max_length': 'Each tag should be no more than 50 characters.'}
        ),
        max_length=3,
        write_only=True,
        error_messages={'required': 'You need to add at least one tag to your question.'}
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ('user', 'status', 'topics')
```

The error message: `You need to add at least one tag to your question.` is not being thrown when the list is empty, instead the default error message is thrown: `This field is required." How can I make it so that my custom error message is displayed instead?

Comment: Try: allow_empty=False and change the key to 'empty'.

Comment: share complete error message

Comment: @Melvyn Which key?

Comment: `error_message={'empty': 'You need to add at least one tag to your question.'}` (the key in the error dict).